# Hide row <tr> without removing from DOM

Tags: html, css, angular, dom

I have a table with a search function. The search function takes the table element and iterate over all the rows to check if there is something in `innerText` that matches (maybe this whole implementation in not ideal, feel free to comment).

The problem here, is that I would like to keep every rows in the DOM so any new search will take all the rows into account. On the other hand, I would like the search to hide all the non matching rows.

I thought it would be easy to find the solution here but I didn't find... What I've tried so far:

- `display: none` - remove from DOM
- `visiblity:hidden` - keep the space of the row
- `height: 0px` - doesn't work... my  have a higher height and 0px doesn't have any effect

I'm trying to avoid using JQuery and use Angular 2 (v4) tools instead

***Edit***: here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/C9E8LolkvdEXWx7eWsLv?p=preview) of my implementation

Comment: A Plunker to reproduce would be helpful.

Comment: If you're using CSS to `display:none`, it shouldn't remove it from the DOM. CSS doesn't have the ability to affect the DOM.

Comment: As @Albzi said, `display: none;` cannot remove an element from your DOM. It just frees the space that the element takes up. You can hide it by default and show it on a new search using `display: block;` or `display: table-cell;` (depends on your markup).

Comment: I have tried this using jquery.if you want to hide data so you may use this.here my search string is "text" .It will hide table row contains "text"`$('td:contains("text")').parent().toggle();`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I realized that the problem is in the `innerText` please see the plunker (edit)

Comment: @Albzi display:none; removes it when you use a screen reader. It can be an accessibility issue.

Comment: You should choose a different approach. Use something like `<ng-container *ngFor="let item of data"><tr *ngIf="!item.hidden"><td>{{item.name}}</td><td>{{item.color}}</td></tr></ng-container>` and just manipulate `data` in code and let do Angular the DOM updating.

Comment: The problem is still there (innerText won't see the text)... I will close this question and write a new one

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position`:

```css
.hide {
  position: absolute;/* remove from flow*/
  right: 100%;/* send outside screen area */
}
/* is it there ? */
table:hover .hide {
   position:static;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>th</th>
      <th>th</th>
      <th>th</th>
      <th>th</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hide">
      <td>hidden-row</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Another option if content is only text to hide , `font-size` & `line-height`:

```css
.hide {
  font-size:0;/* hide text */
  line-height:0;/* reduce line-height*/
  letter-spacing:0.46rem; /* eventually reset letter-spacing  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <input type="text" (input)="filter($event.target.value)" />
  <table #table=''>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Favorite Color</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>Yellow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hide">
      <td>Michelle</td>
      <td>Purple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mike</td>
      <td>Blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Red</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```